# Elastic Beanstalk: Error during deployment "Engine execution has encountered an error."

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my code on EB however I get this error:

```
Engine execution has encountered an error.
```

I can deploy an earlier version of the app fine. But after I added dynamodb related code, I can no longer deploy the latest version. Not sure if it is related. How can I dig in more?

Logs show:

```
startProcess Failure: starting process "web" failed: Command /bin/sh -c systemctl start web.service failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:Job for web.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status web.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Answer (score 3):

My usual troubleshooting steps are the same as the ones in [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Troubleshooting doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/troubleshooting.html):

1. Retrieve and investigate [EB Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html)
2. If retrieved logs are not helpful, then [SSH to the EC2 instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.ec2connect.html) can be used to get more details or check that the instance config is really what I expected for example.

The error message in this question suggests to run those commands on the instance:

```
systemctl status web.service
journalctl -xe
```